# Should a test scenario prepare all of its required data?

Tags: bdd, acceptance-testing, functional-testing, specflow

Consider a BDD scenario with some given steps that refer to existence of a set of data in database. For example consider the following scenario steps:

Given there is an active customer
When as and admin I change the email of the customer to 'xyz@gmail.com'
Then an email verification message is sent to the customer

My question: which one is the best practice for implementing such Given steps:
1. Create a customer in database with the mentioned data from scratch?
or 2. Query the database and work on existing data with proper state if exists.

Note that most of real scenarios have are much more complex Given steps than the sample I used here.

For the second option, we can use a backup of production databases in test environment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been cross-posted to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/20088/should-a-test-scenario-prepare-all-of-its-required-data

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info): http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/20088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up the appropriate data as part of the givens. That way the scenario is completely self-contained. Having a test database requires tacit knowledge (which customers are considered "active"?) or end up with data for obscure corner cases (I need a customer with two previous purchases and three items in their current basket.) And I agree with the other answers that you should never depend on production data for anything other than exploratory or performance testing, and even then the data should be suitably sanitised and anonymised to avoid accidents.

When you are implementing the steps, the Givens should do whatever they need to set up the world ready for the "When" step. For instance they can insert data directly into a database. They don't need to go via any application interfaces or UIs as long as the application ends up in a consistent state to check the behaviour you are interested in (the When step).

The When step should interact with the application exactly the way the stakeholder would. So if the scenario is about a user doing something, the When step should interact with the user interface. Finally, the Then steps do whatever they need to check the outcome. Again they can check data directly in a database, or check that expected messages were emitted, etc.

I think of it as allowing the Givens and Thens to "cheat" in the name of expediency, but the When step always has to play by the rules and interact with the application correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is a third option. You create a separate test database with known contents and you write your tests against that.
In between test cases, or in the set-up a test case, you make sure that this test database contains the known, well-defined data set, so that changes made in one test case don't affect the next test cases.

I would never write my tests against the production database, especially not tests that might change the database contents. For most businesses, production data is just too valuable to risk in that way.

Comment: Actually, I meant using a backup of production database.

Comment: Then how should we write then given steps?

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat: You do whatever is needed to bring the system in the right state, which can range from doing nothing at all to selecting a specific test database that has the right data-set for this precondition.

Comment: When working on new or small systems, I find it useful to use an in-memory database that I can drop and re-create between test suites. You can populate it with as much or as little data as you need. The only issues I've had are when I need to use DB-specific syntax for certain operations (e.g. `MINUS` vs `SUBTRACT`).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau
You are right. But I also want to have a "BDD scenario" that completely explain what the initial state is (in an understandable way). So I need to use several complicated given steps. Restoring a test database as a given step, actually is not an understandable given step.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to have a production working database in order to run your tests.

Also, querying and altering a production database when doing tests is generally a pretty bad idea. You want your tests to work in isolation.

So, make a fake customer before your test. Use it. Delete it.
If the creation is too complex, you could prepare a whole database for testing purposes. It should have the exact same structure than the production database. Then you'd only have to launch tests using this very database.

Comment: Actually, I meant using a backup of production database.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes take small steps. I think the best way is to prepare the scenario with the fake and small database instead of the real production database. You can copy some of the rows and as soon as you succeed then try for the real data.

Comment: That's OK. The question is how should we write the given step for such situation.